# Possible to use our own EC2 instance as internet gateway in vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, amazon-vpc

If i have a vpc of subnet 10.0.0.0/16 and have a subnet, 10.0.4.0/24. If i want to provide internet connectivity to server in subnet 10.0.4.0/24 from an server in subnet 10.0.0.0/24 , would it be possible?

I dont want to use a NAT gateway , or give EIP to instances itself. i only want one EC2 server in 10.0.0.0/16 and want all servers in its other small subnets to route all internet traffic through one gateway (the EC2 i have with internet)

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i want to provide internet connectivity to server in subnet
>   10.0.4.0/24 from an server in subnet 10.0.0.0/24 , would it be possible?

Yes, of course.

You'll need to:

1. Ensure that source/dest check is disabled on the NAT/gateway host.
2. Set firewall rules such that systems in 10.0.4.0/24 are able to communicate with your NAT host.
3. Create a default route in the route table for 10.0.4.0/24 that points to the ENI of your NAT host.

It goes without saying that you'll need to ensure that NAT is set up properly in the networking stack of the NAT host.

Comment: Ummmm, what? Not sure I understand.